# How to browse large .sql dump on local machine

Tags: mysql, sql, dump

I have a large .sql dump (1,1GB) and want to browse it on my local linux computer. I tried several programs (MySQL Workbench shows it very unsorted, also says codefolding disabled ? DBBrowser seems like it does not import it, when I select the DB via ipmort I get an empty db...counldn't figure out the dbvisualizer and thought maybe it's better to ask some experts about this).

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: By ".sql dump" do you mean a file with a bunch of SQL statements to create and populate a database? If so... A robust text editor. Or a pager like `less`.

Comment: I'm a noob on this - when I open the file in mysqlworkbench it looks like this : https://imgur.com/a/a4gjtJa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **massive** files I usually open a terminal and use the `less` program. All other nicer full GUI editors and visualizers are not that great for huge files.

`less` comes preinstalled in all Linux machines, but not in Unix ones. As the ancient proverb says, *"less is much more than more"*.

You can use it as simple as typing:

```
less my_file.sql
```

A few commands will help you going through:

- `page up/down` to move forward/backwards.
- search forward: `/`
- search backward: `?`
- go to a specific line: `:`
- get file stats (size, lines, etc): `=`

`less` is very powerful and optimized. It's a small miracle, and has a ton of commands you can use. Look at [less man-pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html).